# Crashed my octave installation on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, installation, octave

I am a beginner in learning ubuntu and I've crashed my octave somehow.
I first did

`sudo apt-get install octave`

which installed octave pretty fine, version 4.0.0. I decided (for some compability issues) to install octave 3.8.2 manually, i.e. compiling the sources, so downloaded the corresponding source files and I did

`./configure && make && make install`

Then I decided to remove the 3.8.2 version by doing a

`make uninstall`

After that I could not start my original octave via the command line as it says:

`bash: /usr/local/bin/octave: No such file or directory`

I decided to do

`sudo apt-get remove octave`

and then

`sudo apt-get install octave`

but that did not work. 
Can anybody help me on this issue and explain why my last step of removing octave via the package manager and then re-installing it did not bring back my original state?

Comment: try with `sudo apt-get purge octave*`

Comment: If I am doing that I get an error message: Unable to locate package octave-cli ...

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why are you trying to go back from 4.0 to 3.8? Have you considered trying the 4.2.0-rc2?

Comment: I am doing a course on coursera (probabilistic graphical models) and there was an error when I tried to submit the corresponding assigments in this course. Nobody could help me on the coursera forums as they do not seem to know what the problem is. Therefore I tried to use an octave version which was tested by the mentors there and that was octave version 3.8.2 but that didn't really help as I get another error on the submit

Comment: How do you "submit" the assignment?

Comment: I submit it by just calling the function submit which is provided by the course staff. There seems to be a patch to use but unfortunately, I cannot access it as I've switched to another course session due to time issues and now I am not able to access the forum of the older session anymore ... Seems like I have to ask the same question in the new session forum once again ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build Octave from source chances are you used the default prefix so Octave will be at `/usr/local/bin/`. Your package manager would install Octave at `/usr/bin/`.  Your error message is complaining about a missing octave at `/usr/local/bin/` which means for some reason it's looking for your old installation.

But that's not how the shell works. When you start octave at the command line, the shell does not care where Octave is, it will look for it on the path.  If Octave is missing, the error is different:

```
$ not-octave
-bash: not-octave: command not found
```

Your error comes when the path is already defined.  Do you happen to have an alias that specifies the path?  Maybe you set an alias and forgot about it (see `.bashrc` or `.profile` files):

```
$ alias not-octave='/usr/local/bin/not-octave'
$ not-octave 
-bash: /usr/local/bin/not-octave: No such file or directory
```

Whatever it is that you have done, your system is looking for it in the wrong place. You are still able to call the octave installed by your package manager by specifying its path:

```
$ /usr/bin/octave -q --no-gui
octave:1>
```

Comment: Very good answer.  The key, really, is that the _package management_ installs below `/usr` and your _local from-source_ installation goes to `/usr/local`.  They do not overlap.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I even now can start octave normally again. I closed my terminal and re-opened a new one and now it works. I do not know where this came from, however.